# Spring reactive boot app (2.0.0.RC1) as servlet in WebLogic 12c starts but NPE thrown on access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, weblogic, reactive

Running Spring boot reactive application based off of 2.0.0.RC1. It works by itself with a netty embedded container just fine.

Switching it to a servlet, sorting out the dependencies - exclusions, provisions, weblogic.xml instructions etc, then deploying to WebLogic 12c (12.1.3) container will start the application successfully. However when trying to access the rest url, handled by a single controller, WebLogic throws NPE. It never reaches Spring controller.

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:761)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.__run(WebAppServletContext.java:3417)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1632)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I will paste the excerpts of all relevant sources below. First boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"ca.corp.uservice", "ca.corp.uservice.filecache"})
//@ImportResource({"/WEB-INF/ws-dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
//@EnableWebSecurity
public class FileCacheBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FileCacheBootApp.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(FileCacheBootApp.class);
  }
  ...
}
```

Next the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/filecache")
public class FileCacheController implements FileCacheApi {

  @Autowired
  private FileCacheRepository repo;

  // -------------- GET ---------------

  @GetMapping(value = "{token}")
  @Override public Mono<FileCacheable> get(@PathVariable("token") String token) {
    return repo.findByToken(token).map(f -> load(f));
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "app")
  @Override public Mono<FileCacheable> get(@RequestParam Long appid, @RequestParam String type, @RequestParam Integer langcode) {
    return repo.findByUnique(appid, type, langcode).map(f -> load(f));
   }

  @GetMapping(value = "zip")
  @Override public Mono<FileCacheable> get(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam Integer langcode) {
    return repo.findByNameAndLang(name, langcode);
  }
  ...
}
```

And finally pom, spring fmw and servlet. Needed to do some jumps here to get it to run w/o conflicts in WebLogic container.

```
    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SERVLET, VALIDATION and EL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b09</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Weblogic.xml

```
<weblogic-version>12.1.3</weblogic-version>

<context-root>file-cache-uservice</context-root>

<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

I am trying to be as specific as possible w/o being an info overkill. If you'd like to know more details though... be glad to provide.

Any info or a pointer on the source of the NPE is appreciated.

Comment: It would seem like that my controller is not being registered at all. The NPE was due to the folliowing code: response.sendError(status, message); from the ErrorPageFilter. Status is 404 and message is null. But once I fill those values from within debugger then the container comes back as the usual 404 not recognized. I've also added the error page controller (implements ErrorController) but still fails. ...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. This bit was confusing... I added a dependency for the boot-web back in:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and then everything started responding. Which kind of makes sense except for the fact that you **can't** have that dependency if you run WebFlux boot stand alone.

It's a bit unclear as to why standalone (embedded container) **cannot** have web dependency, and external container **must** have it. But it works now.